# primefaces nested tabview and tabs, not able to scroll tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

Am trying to use primefaces tabview, if we use this tabView as nested tabView then we are not able to scroll tabs in second tabView, for example, if there are many tabs inside tabview we cant scroll in 2nd/3rd tabView.

Below is my code:

```
    <p:tabView scrollable="true">
    <p:tab title="Tab 1">
        aaaaaaaaa
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Tab 2">
        <p:panel>
            <p:tabView scrollable="true">
                <p:tab title="Tab 1">Tab 1 Content</p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Tab 2">
                    <p:panel>
                        <p:tabView scrollable="true">
                            <p:tab title="Tab 1">Tab 1 Content</p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Tab 2">Tab 2 Content</p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Tab 3">Tab 3 Content</p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Tab 4">Tab 4 Content</p:tab>
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            <p:tab title="Tab 25">Tab 25 Content</p:tab>               
                        </p:tabView>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Tab 3">Tab 3 Content</p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Tab 4">Tab 4 Content</p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Tab 5">Tab 5 Content</p:tab>
                .
                .
                .
                <p:tab title="Tab 25">Tab 25 Content</p:tab>               
            </p:tabView>
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Tab 3">Tab 3 Content</p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Tab 4">Tab 4 Content</p:tab>
    .
    .
    .
    <p:tab title="Tab 25">Tab 25 Content</p:tab>               
</p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile this seemes to be fixed with version 5.3 of Primefaces (Oct, 2015).

I can reproduce it with version 5.2.

Version 5.3 adds the scroll controls if space is to small to show all tabs on initial rendering. Version 5.2 doesn't for nested tabViews if not initially visible.

As of version 6.2, the scrollable feature has an additional enhancment and activates/deactivates the controlls when resizing the viewport.